# How can I access a variable located in an adapter class from main activity

Tags: kotlin

I want to access a variable in an adapter class called `item` so that I could use it in my main activity. So far I've tried adding `open` before the adapter class and using `object and companion object`. How can I fix this problem?

```
class GrammarAdapter(private val context: Context, private val items: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<GrammarAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(binding: GrammarItemRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val tvItem = binding.tvItemName
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            GrammarItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.tvItem.text = item



        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            when (item) {
                "Countable and uncountable nouns" -> {
                    val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, CountableUncountable::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("clickedGrammarTopic", item)
                    holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                }
                "Singular and plural nouns" -> {
                    val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, Singular and plural nouns::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("clickedGrammarTopic", item)
                    holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                }
...
```

Comment: I've checked that one before asking the question but it was all in Java and for a beginner like me it is impossible to make the connection with Kotlin.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I provide

Answer (score 1):

As long as `items` is not private you can do something like:

```
val item = (myRecycler.adapter as MyAdapterClass).items[position]
```

However thats not really the best practice and you may want to rethink how your managing your apps data perhaps you should look into ViewModels

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used my .adapter as a view binder. Can I bother you to have a look at a couple more lines? I just edited the question. This is my first time coding with kotlin so I hope I didn't make your eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the callback pattern via an interface

```
interface Callback {
    fun onClickedRow(item: String)
}
```

In the adapter constructor

```
class GrammarAdapter(... , private val callback: Callback) : ...
```

And modify the interaction

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    callback.onClickedRow(item)
}
```

You have to implement the interface in the activity or fragment

```
clas MyFragment : Callback {

    override fun onClickedRow(item: String) {
         //do something here with your item
    }
}
```

And instantiate your adapter with the callback as an argument

```
val adapter = GrammarAdapter(..., this@MyFragment) //depending on your scope it can be simple this
```

Now when the user clicks the method `override fun onClickedRow(...` is going to be triggered on the activity or fragment